# ¿Double execution of python's __init__.py file?

Tags: python, django

Im doing some tests with [django](https://www.djangoproject.com/), but I'm having a problem with what it seems to be a double execution of the my __init__.py.

Why is it being executed two times?

Example:

```
$ ./manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:9000
Trying import local.py settings...
Trying import development.py settings...
Trying import local.py settings...
Trying import development.py settings...
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
November 06, 2015 - 10:13:51
Django version 1.8.6, using settings 'settings'
Starting development server at http://0.0.0.0:9000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
```

File tree:

```
$ tree -I '*.pyc'
.
├── db.sqlite3
├── manage.py
└── settings
    ├── development.py
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── local.py.example
    ├── __pycache__
    ├── urls.py
    └── wsgi.py
```

manage.py file:

```
$ more manage.py 
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "settings")

    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line

    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

settings/__init___.py file:

```
$ more settings/__init__.py 
from __future__ import absolute_import, print_function
import os, sys

try:
    print("Trying import local.py settings...", file=sys.stderr)
    from .local import *
except ImportError:
    print("Trying import development.py settings...", file=sys.stderr)
    from .development import *
```

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django's `manage.py runserver` by default forks a child process from the main process.

If you add `print('PID:', os.getpid(), 'Parent PID:', os.getppid())` to your `__init__.py` you will see that you get 2 numbers each line, the PID and the parent thread PID.

The output should look like this, more or less:

`PID: 31019 Parent PID: 30633
PID: 31020 Parent PID: 31019`

What you see here is the following:

30633 = shell PID.

31019 = manage.py runserver parent process.

31020 = manage.py runserver child process.

The reason actually lies in the default runserver behavior, to use a reloader. What it does is basically boot up manage.py runserver as a parent process. if you did not specify the --noreload option, then it will spawn a child `manage.py runserver` process.

After doing that, the parent runserver will track code changes so it can kill and reload the child process.

If you run `manage.py runserver --noreload` you will see that you get only one line of PID, Parent PID.

For more information about this, you can dig into Django's runserver command that resides in django.core.management.commands

Comment: Superb explanation. Thank you very much.